# (Linux) how to make wait watch sub-process of a sub-process

Tags: linux, shell, wait

The code I am trying to use (shell script in korn) is this:

```
load_x ()
{
consumer_load &
producer_spool
}

while read line
do
  load_x &
done < list_of_loads
wait
```

In a nutshell I am trying to read a list of tables from a flat file, then triggering their loads in parallel. I am also triggering the consumer_load function in background so that the producer_spool function can feed data to it through a named pipe.
The issue I am facing is that the wait statement does not seem to work for the inner sub-process fired in background (consumer_load &). i.e. it does wait for the load_x function to finish, but does not wait for consumer_load to finish and moves to the next statement.
In this case, if the producer_spool function finishes before consumer_load, the script will end even if the consumer_load is still running.
Is there a way to get a script to wait for all sub-processes? Would putting wait inside load_x (as the last line) work?

Comment: On Unix, processes can only wait for their own children, there's no way to deal with grandchildren.

Comment: Yes, `wait` inside `load_x` should work.

Comment: So can a child process wait for grandchild process? What if I wait within the load_x function?

Comment: I just answered both questions. You can't wait for a grandchild, and I think wait inside load_x will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to my question was posted by Barmar. I am still verifying it, but based on what I see it should work.

```
load_x ()
{
consumer_load &
producer_spool
wait # Waits for consumer_load process to finish before exiting load_x
}

while read line
do
  load_x &
done < list_of_loads
wait
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should:

```
load_x ()
{
    (
         consumer_load &
         producer_spool
         wait 
    )
}
```

Otherwise load_x assumes it's always runs in the background, and if it were not, its "wait" would await other background pids too.